# TypeError: $wrapper.isotope is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jquery-isotope

I am facing this error while I go to use isotopejs plugin on reactjs component to implement the image gallery  ...
actually, what's the prime mistake I have done can not detect...
Have anyone implement the isotope plugin in the react.js component if so please kindly see my issue...

```
var $wrapper = $(".portfolio_wrapper");

  // Isotop initialize

  $wrapper.isotope({
    filter: "web",
    layoutMode: "masonry",
    animation: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: "linear",
    },
  });
```

Comment: Have you jquery installed in your React app? If not you should implement Isotope with vanilla Javascript like this: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#initialize-with-vanilla-javascript

Comment: Yes, jQuery is installed. I want to use isopejs plugin for photo gallary in my react.js project